# Will a series of 5' vertical tubings filled with water create a vacuum at the top of the tube that is equivalent to one 30' length of tubing?

Tags: water, vacuum

It's been proven that a vertical 30' length of 3/16 tubing filled with water creates maximum vacuum at the top end.  Basically, the tube is small enough in diameter that no air passes and the weight of the water creates the vacuum. This principle is used for vacuum in maple sap collection. Now suppose i would have 6 pieces of tubing side by side, each 5' length and connected at the top with a series of Ts or a spider.  Will that give me the vacuum equivelent to one 30' lenght?

Comment: Whatever 3/16 tubing may be ... I guess some strange measure of diameter, if so it is irrelevant for answering the question. Note that physics.SE is about conceptual questions about physics, so it is considered good style to reduce context that is irrelevant for the physics at play.

Answer (score 0):

no, it will not. the pressures inside them do not add (or subtract) that way.